# Computing point operations on an elliptic curve over a finite field

Tags: cryptography

I'm working on a homework problem that asks you to compute $1943(1980,431)$, where $p = 2671$, $E:Y^2=X^3+171X+853$, and $P=(1980,431) \in E(F_{2671})$.

I found the ternary expansion of $1943$ to be $1943=-2^0-2^3+2^5-2^7+2^{11}$. Thus $1943P=-P-2^3P+2^5P-2^7P+2^{11}P$, so computing $1943P$ using the double-and-add algorithm requires $11$ doublings and $4$ additions. However, this seems inefficient to do by hand.

How do I use Mathematica to compute point operations on an elliptic curve?

Comment: @user64494 In the post you linked to, the most interesting thing I see are [EllipticLog](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EllipticLog.html) and [EllipticExp](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EllipticExp.html). But I do not see how they are applicable to the question at hand (an elliptic curve over a finite field) or why this question would be a duplicate of that question. Can you explain? 3 people have agreed with you, so maybe I am missing something.

Comment: Hi. I just saw that you edited the title. If you have an interest in getting this reopened, then you should edit your post and write a sentence or two that directly addresses why [this thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/127779/plotting-the-sum-of-two-points-on-an-elliptic-curve) does not answer your question. Your question was first closed by 5 people, and an attempt to reopen was denied by another 3 people, so it is not going to work unless you explain with some clarity why this is not a duplicate. The title edit does help a little bit but is probably not enough.

Comment: @user293787 I ran into a problem when computing $(3,6)+(3,1)$ in $E(F_7):Y^2=X^3+2X+3$. Because x1=x2 and y1=-y2, $(3,6)+(3,1)=O$ but the code outputs $(3,6)+(3,1)=(6,0)$.

Comment: No it does not, I just tried, it gives `Infinity`, which is your $O$.

Comment: If I copy-paste the code and then use the following:

Needs["FiniteFields`"];
kk = GF[7][{#}] &;

(*elliptic curve*)a = kk[2];
b = kk[3];
e[{x_, y_}] := y^2 - (x^3 + a*x + b);

P = {kk[2], kk[1]};

then mult[a][53,P] gives (2,6) when it should give infinity. 

And when I compute {kk[3],kk[6]}+{kk[3],kk[1]} I get (6,0).

Comment: Not `+`, it should be `add[a][{kk[3], kk[6]}, {kk[3], kk[1]}]`. Will not be able to provide more help. You can always ask a new question if you want. Good luck.

Comment: @user293787 sorry I mixed up the calculations, doing it by hand confirms that 53P = (2,6) while 54P=infinity, which is exactly the same as what your code gives. Thank you :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There probably is some way to do this using built-in functionality, but anyhow, here is an implementation of the [group law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve#Algebraic_interpretation) (use at your own risk):

```
add[a_][P:{xP_,yP_},Q:{xQ_,yQ_}]:=If[And[xP===xQ,yP===-yQ],Infinity,
  With[{s=If[xP===xQ,(3*xP^2+a)/(2*yP),(yP-yQ)/(xP-xQ)]},
    With[{xR=s^2-xP-xQ},
      {xR,-yP-s*(xR-xP)}]]];
add[a_][Infinity,Infinity]=Infinity;
add[a_][Infinity,Q_]:=Q;
add[a_][P_,Infinity]:=P;

add[a_][P_]:=P;
add[a_][P_,Q_,Ps__]:=add[a][add[a][P,Q],Ps];

mult[a_][n_Integer/;n>=0,P_]:=With[{ds=IntegerDigits[n,2]},
  add[a]@@Pick[NestList[add[a][#,#]&,P,Length[ds]-1]//Reverse,ds,1]];
```

We can now calculate:

```
Needs["FiniteFields`"];
kk=GF[2671][{#}]&;

(* elliptic curve *)
a=kk[171];
b=kk[853];
e[{x_,y_}]:=y^2-(x^3+a*x+b);

(* calculation requested by OP *)
P={kk[1980],kk[431]};

(* 1st method, slow *)
Q=add[a]@@ConstantArray[P,1943]

(* 2nd method, faster *)
Q=mult[a][1943,P]

(* check that we are still on the curve *)
e[Q]
(* 0 *)
```

Both methods give the following result for `Q`:

```
{GF[2671, {0, 1}][{1432}], GF[2671, {0, 1}][{667}]}
```

that is $(1432,667)$.

---

**Discrete log.** This is naive code that tries to find an integer $n\geq 0$ such that $nP=Q$:

```
discreteLog[a_][P_,Q_]:=First[NestWhile[{#[[1]]+1,add[a][P,#[[2]]]}&,
                                        {0,Infinity},(#[[2]]=!=Q)&]];

(* Example using same points as before *)
discreteLog[a][{kk[1980],kk[431]},{kk[1432],kk[667]}]
(* 624 *)
```

See also [this answer from 2015](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/97183/85954).

Comment: I tried using the code but couldn't get the correct answer. 

    In[20]:= 1943 P

    Out[20]= {Subscript[{900}, 2671], Subscript[{1410}, 2671]}

Comment: You cannot simply write `1943*P` since that will do something else. Use `add[a]@@ConstantArray[P,1943]` instead (you can create a shorthand for this kind of thing if necessary) or the second method using doublings.

Comment: Using add[a]@@ConstantArray[P,1943] gives the following If[False, 
Missing["NotStored"], 
If[19998936696054143456 === $SessionID, 
Out[23], Message[
MessageName[Syntax, "noinfoker"]]; Missing["NotAvailable"]; Null]]

Comment: The output gives a box containing "add[{171}_2671] and a list of identical numbers {1980}_2671 and {431}_2671.

Comment: If I `Quit[]` to make sure that no previous definitions interfere, then copy & paste the code I posted here into a notebook (all of it, including the definition of `add`, and in the order I posted it) then I get the result $(1432,667)$. I use version 12.3.

Comment: I did that, but now I'm getting a long list of P's of the form add[a] [P,P,...,P], which I think is going from 1 to 1943. I'm using the 13.1 student edition.

Comment: If you include `P={kk[1980],kk[431]}`... then no, you are not going to  get what you say. Sorry but it is difficult to remote troubleshoot.

Comment: Something to adjust. Your code results in `{Subscript[{1432}, 2671], Subscript[{667}, 2671]}`, not in `{1432,667}` for me in 13.1 on Windows 10.

Comment: @user293787 it's working now! I was not evaluating the input cells to make the assignments work before computing.

Comment: Follow-up question: how do I use the code to calculate x such that x(1980,431) = some point on the elliptic curve?

Comment: Added a function `mult` to do that. Please see the "2nd method" as an example.

Comment: @user293787 I'm having trouble figuring this out. Using mult[P] gives the point whose elliptic discrete logarithm with respect to P is what I'm looking for. But how would I find the value of this elliptic discrete logarithm? I want to find the smallest such integer, but I'm not sure how to use the code also to find the order of P.

Comment: @Karam Sorry, I had misunderstood. Please see the edit.

Comment: @user293787 that works!